# Angular 2 - why ng test ignore TS compilation error?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-testing

i create some TS error in my test (spec file) such: 
`let num: number = "dsds"`.

- i run the ng test and the test is successful... why?
- i expected to get some TS error in the terminal
- What i need to do to enable this behavior (the TS catch error) when running tests?
- Details:

  - @angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.31
  - node: 6.9.2
  - os: win32 x64
  - @angular/common: 2.4.7
  - @angular/compiler: 2.4.7
  - @angular/core: 2.4.7
  - @angular/forms: 2.4.7
  - @angular/http: 2.4.7
  - @angular/platform-browser: 2.4.7
  - @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.7
  - @angular/router: 3.4.7
  - @angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.31
  - @angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.7

Comment: Can you show us your test code?

Comment: sure but is really obviuos one because it related to the TS comipilition error.

`it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    let num: number = "dsds";
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `ng test` to catch it while compiling, you have to write a separate test case for this element. You can use, e.g. `RegExp` object to check if it is or it's not a number.

```
it('should be a number', () => {
  expect(component.num).toMatch(/\d+/);
});
```

**Edit**:

If you declare a following variable:

```
someNumberVar: number = "thisIsNotANumber";
```

the TypeScript will catch it as an error, but while **compiling** the app, not while **testing**! You can check it out by yourself, set this variable and start the compilation, by typing `ng serve` in the console. You will receive following error:

**`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'`.**

In case if you would like to **test** your application, you have to write a separate test cases for each element you want to test, as I mentioned above.

Comment: mm but why? This is an TS compilation error not a logic error or runtime exception..

Comment: @user2415300 Edited my post.

Comment: so what u say is that the type script compile error will NOT catch when u run testing, just on Build/running the app?

Comment: @user2415300 If you don't make a test case for it - nope.

Comment: It all depends on what you're expecting it looks like num could be a string containing only numeric values. If that's the case you should use `string` as the type. If it could be a string or a number use the the type `string | number` and so on. In other words the type should reflect the domain of values you expect it to take at runtime.

Comment: @user2415300, Thanks For Answer,

Comment: @AluanHaddad u didnt understand my question was:  why ng test ignore TS compilation error?

Comment: I did understand it. I just thought it was already explained by others. Unless what you're testing is a declaration file, tests always test runtime behavior they run after compilation has occurred. You can prevent typescript from emitting code if there is a compilation error with the  `--noEmitOnError` flag. Otherwise you're testing the compiler, not your code. This is just a generally how statically typed languages work and it makes a lot of sense. For example if you use ts-node to run your tests, you actually will get a failure when you run your test command but it will come from compilation